# Utilizing the touchpad on gearVR in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Still learning here and starting of with basics (just a plain Plane and moving as the first person around) 
However i can run the app and look around and up and down etc. but can;t make the camera move when touching the touchpad on the GearVR headset.

I have created the script (c#) and attached to the camera in unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Tap"))
    {
        // Do something if tap starts
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Tap"))
    {
        // Do something if tap ends

    }
}

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButton("Tap"))
    {
        // Do something if tap starts
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Tap"))
    {
        // Do something if tap ends
    }

}
}
```

But it still doesn't seem to work.  When i build and run the app it does nothing :-(

I know i am doing something wrong but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Single Tap in Oculus Gear VR:**

```
void Start()
{
    OVRTouchpad.Create();
    OVRTouchpad.TouchHandler += OVRTouchpad_TouchHandler;
}


void OVRTouchpad_TouchHandler (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OVRTouchpad.TouchArgs touchArgs = (OVRTouchpad.TouchArgs)e;
    OVRTouchpad.TouchEvent touchEvent = touchArgs.TouchType;
    if(touchArgs.TouchType == OVRTouchpad.TouchEvent.SingleTap)
    {
        // Your response to Tap goes here.
    }
}
```

**Tap and Hold to Move:**

1. You need to register `Tap`key in your input following [this
   tutorial.](http://talesfromtherift.com/gearvr-input-touchpad/)
2. Add OVRPlayerController prefab to move around the scene. This will
   let you move using keyboard W/A/S/D keys in Unity Editor.
3. Next you need to integrate Tap key with OVR Player controller script
   to move in forward direction.

here are some useful links:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/gear-vr-touchpad-fps-script.373103/

http://rifty-business.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/unity-pro-4-using-ovrcameracontroller.html